# Override jvmArguments for Maven spring boot plugin

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, jvm-arguments

I have this plugin config in my pomn:

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <jvmArguments>
                     -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=${project.build.outputDirectory}/keystore.jks
                     -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=ue90D3v
                     -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=${project.build.outputDirectory}/keystore.jks
                     -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=ue90D3v
                </jvmArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

So I can run app perfectly by mvn spring-boot:run. But what if I want to **override** arguments, for example "javax.net.ssl.trustStore". I expect this command works:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=<other_location>
```

But it doesn't.  Also I tried this and not working :

```
mvn -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=other_location" spring-boot:run
```

Also it would be a solution if I can set JAVA_OPTS in pom.

Comment: Related: [#3646 -Drun.jvmArguments has no effect if jvmAguments are specified in the pom.xml](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3646)

Answer (score 8):

facing the same problem, you can do this:

```
<properties>
  <!-- defined here if you don't use -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments-->
  <spring-boot.run.jvmArguments></spring-boot.run.jvmArguments>
</properties>
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <jvmArguments>
                 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=${project.build.outputDirectory}/keystore.jks
                 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=ue90D3v
                 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=${project.build.outputDirectory}/keystore.jks
                 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=ue90D3v 
                 ${spring-boot.run.jvmArguments}
            </jvmArguments>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

and starting you app with:

```
mvn -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=other_location" spring-boot:run
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I didn't find `spring-boot.run.jvmArguments` documented anywhere!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=other_location"
```

Doc link : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/run-debug.html

Used the same in past for some other arguments.

Comment: it seems when you have jvmArguments in pom, it is not gonna be overridden.