# how to provide multiple plugins of Same Artifact in Pom.xml

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml

Could Someone please help me with writing multiple executions and configuration on different classes for same Artifact(i.e. `spring-boot-maven-plugin`)
Currently I am writing this as follows but I don't think so it is working :

```
<build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>lombok-execution</id>
                            <configuration>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>
                                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                                    </exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>jvm-heap-execution</id>
                            <configuration>
                                <mainClass>com.magicbrick.engine.RuleEngineV2Application</mainClass>
                                <executable>true</executable>
                                <jvmArguments>
                                    -Xms1g
                                    -Xmx4g
                                </jvmArguments>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>       
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
```

Here are the two dataset before and after setting JVM heap arguments(**jvm-heap-execution**) in Pom file.

I made a controller which is simply returning these datasets for **same application**:

```
@GetMapping("/status")
    public MemoryStats getMemoryStatistics() {
        MemoryStats stats = new MemoryStats();
        stats.setHeapSize(Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory());
        stats.setHeapMaxSize(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory());
        stats.setHeapFreeSize(Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
        return stats;
    }
```

---

First Dataset are the values before I set custom JVM arguments (**-Xms1g -Xmx4g**)

```
{
    "heapSize": 493355008,
    "heapMaxSize": 2835349504,
    "heapFreeSize": 178130512
}
```

Second Dataset are the values after I set custom JVM arguments (**-Xms1g -Xmx4g**)

```
{
    "heapSize": 550502400,
    "heapMaxSize": 2835349504,
    "heapFreeSize": 356596472
}
```

**heapMaxSize**(2835349504) remains the same in both the cases.

Comment: Why do you think it isn't working? It's unclearhow the datasets you mention refer to the pom snippet. please provide more details.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker : Hi, I updated the question. Please let me know if you need any extra information. Since heapMaxSize remains same before and after setting JVM arguments. That's how I deduce it isn't working. The expected result would be heapMaxSize would be 4gb(~4e+9 bytes)

Comment: Just curious, is there a chance you're providing these same arguments somewhere else?  If so, is there a chance you've hit an upstream "bug"? https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3646, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53525496?

Comment: @tresf : I believe that is not the case. POM is the only place where I am setting these args.